# Modifying PROCTHROTTLEMAX with powercfg has no effect in 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, processor, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to make the CPU transition to a lower P-state. I used pwrtest to determine the tests, and now I want to set the processor frequency to 50%.

I executed the following command:

```
powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 50
```

When i query the scheme, the value is set to the desired value. However, the processor frequency is not modified (I am using CPU-Z to check the frequency).

My system is running Windows 2008 R2.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to call

```
powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT
```

to apply the changes

Answer (score 1):

Thx Alex! Here is the complete script.

## Make the changes

powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMIN 5
powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_CURRENT SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 50

## Apply the changes

powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT